# Run time error for non increasing value of a int recursively C++

Tags: c++, recursion, time, runtime-error

Here is my code. I'm getting a run time error. Is there a better way to procede recursively?
The goal is: taking 3 as the input will result this

- 1 1 1
  2 1
  3

If there is a better way to implement easy recursion, i'm listening

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int divide(int input,int memory) {
    if(memory==input){
        cout<<input;
        exit(1);
        }
    cout<<memory<<" ";
    int i=memory;
    for(i;i<input;i++){
        cout<<1<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    memory++;
    divide(input,memory);
}
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    divide(8,1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the objecitve? What is the error? Pls update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply get a runtime error because of this line:

```
exit(1);
```

Change it to:

```
exit(0);
```

Btw, if you just want to stop the function when `input==memory` instead use:

```
return 0;
```

EDIT: `int divide(int input,int memory) {` this means you must return an `int`. If you don't really need to return anything, change it to:

```
void divide(int input,int memory) {
```

and use: `return;` to stop the recursion

EDIT: Since you asked a cleaner implementation (in my opinion) would be:

```
void divide(int input,int memory) {

    std::vector<int> result(input - memory + 1, 1);
    result.front() = memory;
    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << endl;

    if (input < ++memory) return;
    divide(input,memory);

}
```

Comment: Thanks it did the work, except for the return alone, it says  return-statement with no value, in function returning 'int' [-fpermissive]
   return;

Comment: You need to add a return statement (except the one I mentioned)

Comment: if i may ask, do you have a smarter easier implementation for the problem

Comment: Thanks, i can't yet give a thumbs up, new to the forum and the programming world, appreciate it tho